# Receiving form GET-method request payload empty in expressJS server

Tags: forms, express, http

I'm trying to set up a simple GET API using express JS. When I receive a GET method request from client on form submission, I'm not able to view the request body data despite using

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true}))
```

Please provide any suggestions on how to rectify this.

Client side HTML:

```
  <form method="get" action="/tododetails">
    <label for="typebar"></label>
    <input type = "text" id = "typebar">
    </input>
    <button >
      submit
    </button>
  </form>
```

ExpressJS server:

```
let express = require('express');
let path = require('path');
let app = express();
app.use(express.static('Client'))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true}))
app.get('/tododetails', (req, res) => {
  console.log(res.body);
  res.sendStatus(200);
})
```

I'm expecting to get the request data in readable JSON format in expressJS so I can carry on processing it for further usage.

Comment: Just a note, why `res.body`? It is `req.body`